# ES6: Destructure methods from class/function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering if it's possible to destructure the properties/methods from an instance of a class or function while maintaining scope across the destructured variables? For example:

```
function Counter() {
  this.state = {count: 0}
  this.update = (fragment) => {
    this.state = Object.assign({}, this.state, fragment)
  }
  this.increment = () => {
    this.update({count: this.state.count + 1})
  }
  this.decrement = () => {
    this.update({count: this.state.count - 1})
  }
}

const counter = new Counter

const {
  state,
  increment,
  decrement
} = counter

console.log(state)
increment()
console.log(state)
decrement ()
console.log(state)
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yicogo/edit?js,console)

The result for each console.log is the same: `{count: 0}` because it's creating a new instance and new scope for each of the variables.

Is this intentional? Am I approaching this the wrong way? (I'm creating a library and I assume someone will try to use it this way so I want to make it work)

Comment: It works as expected. "I assume someone will try to use it this way so I want to make it work" --- you better not.

Comment: Actually this is a very good question about JS "basic" behavior. +1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910018/how-to-bind-methods-when-destructuring-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

In your example, destructuring desugars to something like

```
const state = counter.state;
```

Assigning a new value to `counter.state` won't magically update the value of `state`. Destructuring doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1):

The object destructure is creating a local const `state` which is a *memory reference* to the current `state` object in the class instance.

```
const {
  state,
  increment,
  decrement
} = counter
```

The `Object.assign` in the `update` method is copying the contents of `state` + `fragment` into a *new, empty* object (at a new memory address...). `this.state` is then being set to that new object.

```
this.update = (fragment) => {
  this.state = Object.assign({}, this.state, fragment)
}
```

The destructured, local const `state` is not reactive - it will continue pointing to the object it was told to point to.

Rather than using a new, empty object in `Object.assign`, you can write directly to `this.state`. As well, you don't need the return value - `Object.assign` mutates.

```
this.update = (fragment) => {
  Object.assign(this.state, fragment)
}
```