# How to bind methods when destructuring an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, this, destructuring

How to bind methods when destructuring an object in JavaScript?

```
const person = {
  getName: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

var a = person.getName;
var b = person.getName.bind(person);
var {getName: c} = person;

person.getName(); //=> {getName: [Function]}
a();              //=> window or global
b();              //=> {getName: [Function]}
c();              //=> window or global
```

I want `c` to log in the console its "parent" object `{getName:
 [Function]}`.

Is there any way to bind all methods when destructuring an object in one *destructuring* line?

Comment: Context is given at invocation time. `var {getName:c} = person;` is the same as `var c = person.getName;`. If you want to give `c` a context of your choice, use `.call`, `.apply` or `.bind`

Comment: I can't think of anything but `var {…} = autobindAllMethods(person)` with a helper function

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, there is no way. Functions detached from objects lose the original context. And destructing in JavaScript has no syntax to do something with extracted values on the fly.

Comment: This would be a great feature!

Answer (score 9):

There is a simple workaround using ES6 classes. You can use `bind` in the class constructor to manually set the context of the function.

In the example below, `getName()` will "survive" the destructuring :

```js
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.getName = this.getName.bind(this);
  }

  getName() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

const {
  getName
} = new Person();

getName(); // Person { getName: [Function: bound getName] }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a getter or a proxy to bind a method whenever you `get` it, even using destructuring.

Both solutions check if method is already bound, by looking for `bound` at the start of the name using [`String.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith). If not bound, that method will be bound before returning it.

1. Auto-bind the method to the object with a getter. This will require a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for each method.

```js
const person = {
  prop: 5,
  _getName: function() {
    console.log(this.prop);
  },
  
  get getName() {
    // if not bound, bind the method
    if(!this._getName.name.startsWith('bound ')) {
      this._getName = this._getName.bind(this);
    }
    
    return this._getName;
  }
};

var a = person.getName;
var b = person.getName.bind(person);
var {getName: c} = person;

person.getName(); //=> 5
a();              //=> 5
b();              //=> 5
c();              //=> 5
```

2. Auto-bind the method to the object with a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Define once for all methods.

```js
var handler = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    // if method, and not bound, bind the method
    if(typeof target[prop] === 'function' && !target[prop].name.startsWith('bound ')) {
      target[prop] = target[prop].bind(target);
    }
    
    return target[prop];
  }
};

const person = new Proxy({
  prop: 5,
  getName: function() {
    console.log(this.prop);
  }
}, handler);

var a = person.getName;
var b = person.getName.bind(person);
var {getName: c} = person;

person.getName(); //=> 5
a();              //=> 5
b();              //=> 5
c();              //=> 5
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use an arrow method:

```
const person = {
  getName: () => console.log(this),
};
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code.  ``getName:``. Replace "=" with ":"

Answer (score 4):

Yes. We can do this with a single line of code, assuming I understood your question correctly.

This certainly isn't the most readable approach, but it's a method that I use often in my personal projects:

```
const person = {
    getName: function() {
      console.log(this);
    }
  };

// IIFE for destructuring and applying changes inline
const { a, b, c } = (({ getName }) => ({ a: getName.bind(person), b: getName.bind(person), c: getName.bind(person) }))(person);
```

Now we call the destructured props:

```
a(); // { getName: [Function: getName] }
b(); // { getName: [Function: getName] }
c(); // { getName: [Function: getName] }
```

What's happening here? If that line was confusing, read on...

We are wrapping everything in an IIFE which accepts as input the `person` object; we pull the `getName` prop inline.<sup>1</sup>

Finally, we are explicitly mapping each call to `bind` using the `getName` prop - as pulled from our sole argument, `person` - to correspond to `a, b, c`, which we are destructuring away from the resolved IIFE.

<sup>1</sup>*OK so I've arguably cheated here in that we have *two* destructuring "statements" but which are ultimately resolved in the same expression*